# Passing touchesMoved events to superview only passes first event

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, touch-event

I've created a subclass of UIButton and have implemented methods for `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesMoved`. I'd like to alert the superview that it needs to carry out some action whenever any touches occur within my control. I first tried this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if(self.superview != nil)
  {
    [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
  }
}
```

The result was bizarre: the first touchesMoved event would correctly bubble up to the superview, but then no more would after that. I tried printing out the pointer values of self.super and self.superview, and they never change, so there's nothing strange going on with memory.

I next tried passing a selector within the parent view controller as a `SEL` type to the custom control, thus creating a kind of callback, but XCode did not like that (I got an error message of "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when running).

I may just implement a protocol for intercepting events from my control (delegate-style) and register my view controller as a delegate of that type. Thoughts?

Comment: Subclassing UIButton is typically not recommended. Apple does some weird stuff behind the scenes with that class. I've had reasonable success subclassing UIControl instead.

Comment: Let me know if that solves it and I'll move it into an answer.

Comment: Actually, I followed a delegate paradigm instead. The user implementing the control has to adhere to a protocol and implement a method specified by the protocol. The user then sets the control's delegate property, and the control performs a callback on the method. Done and done.